# How to prevent lazy initialization when accessing only identifier?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

So I have following mapping of `Comment` entity;

```
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"user", "place"})
@Entity
public class Comment extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Place place;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String comment;

    @Column
    private Integer rating;

    @Column
    private Boolean approved;
}
```

I fetch `Comments` like this

```
 Page<Comment> comments = commentRepository.findByApprovedIsFalseOrApprovedIsNull(pageable);
```

And putting it into view as table like this

```
                    <tr th:each="comment,i : ${comments}">
                        <td><input name="places" th:value="${comment.id}" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td th:text="${comments.number} * ${comments.size} + ${i.count}">LP1</td>
                        <td th:text="${comment.user.id}">1234</td>
                        <td th:text="${comment.place.id}">5432</td>
                        <td th:text="${comment.createdAt}">2014-04-10</td>
                        <td th:text="${comment.comment}">Lorem ipsum and more</td>
                        <td>Location</td>
                    </tr>
```

Now the problem is, that despite `Comment` table (yes, not entity) contains columns `user_id` and `place_id`, additional select are performed to fetch both distinct `Place` and `User` relations. As I am accessing only identifiers of those entities, that should be in fact already hidden under the hood with `Comment`, why would that initialization happen? Is it possible to ommit those extra initialization fetches?

EDIT:

I have checked some sources, and I have found out, that  `BasicLazyInitializer` has the ability to return identifier only just like I require, but I dont know, what conditions must be met on top layer to get this branch appied. Take look here:
[image]

Comment: Did you try by adding fetch and optional attributes i.e., '@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)'?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu but they are lazy by default, and whole questions stands that relations gets lazy initialized whitch is what I wanted to avoid (because it is surplus due to ids fetch only)

Comment: You can map additional fields as suggested below or specify a join fetch in your query which should load all the data in 1 go and  prevent the additional queries for User and Place.

Comment: @Antoniossss Per JPA, '*ToOne' relationships are EAGER by default and '*ToMany' are LAZY by default unless we override them.

Comment: Allright, so I have declared lazy fetch, and the effect is still the same. Proxy gets initialized when getId() is called :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I have a solution that I required. It does not require extra JPQL nor native queries like *pirho* mentioned nor requires obfuscating workaround like *72 Services* suggested.

All we have to do is put `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on `private Long id;` field and define default `@Access(AccessType.Field)` for rest of properties. Nothing of that is required if you are already using property access either by `@Access` annotation, or by annotating with ORM annotation getters instead of fields.

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable=false,nullable=false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;
```

This works like a charm. No N+1 queries while accessing ID fields of relations.

Answer (score 1):

You can map directly to a Pojo

```
public class Response { 

    private Integer userId

    private Integer placeId

    private String comment;

    public Response(Integer userId, Integer placeId, String comment){
     .....
    }


}


@Query("select new Response(c.user.id, c.place.id, c.comment) from Comment c where ....")
private Resposne myCustomQuery(....)
```

Take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-expressions
11.5

Comment: this - if working as wanted - would be the right way, kind a separating view from model, IMHO

Comment: This - is not even close to what I wanted. View-Model separation does not mean that you have to include another transient entity unless its a projection. View should take a model and render it. That is what this separation is about, not about view having no knowledge of model.

Comment: "Kind  a" i stated. Solution you provided was great and applies fine to your problem. But if you need any arbitrary property anytime not only id?

Comment: @pirho then it is a `@Column`, fetching ID is a special usecase of getting "hidden" property. Rest would be mapped as fields.

Comment: @Antoniossss i disagree with you. View have to be different from your model, You can`t expose your model(entity) to view/rest-api.

You can have severel issues as LazyInitializationException. For example when you are render to view:

"${comment.user.id}"

You are creating a new query from your view when you get any  association (in the render phase). because this is not loaded  until you call getxxx methods.

Comment: @Makoton and here where you are wrong. There is no lazy initialization here as proxy for user already have id fetched along with comment entity. This was the whole point of my question, how to avoid that initialization. And I did find nice and clean and universal solution. Adding 2 lines of code, makes all relations behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the foreign keys to separate fields as read only.

```
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer userId;

@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer placeId;
```